# User Profile pictures now shown for all users after MIM sync

Tags: 2016, mim

I've configured MIM 2016 towards AD and SP 2016 on-prem, and successfully imported profiles from AD, including user profile pictures. I have also executed the

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation http://my.company.com -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1
```

and can see the GUID based photo files have now changed to respective _LThumb, _MThumb, _SThumb files in MySite "User Photos" library.

However, the GUID based photo is not getting stored in "User Photos" library, nor the 3 pictures getting generated for **for all users**. E.g., I have two subsequent users from same OU, and both have thumbnailPhoto set in their AD profile, still only one of them end up getting the the GUIC pic and eventually the 3 pictures in the User Photos library.

MIM Metaverse Object properties for the users who don't end up getting the picture do, however, contain the picture just fine, just like the users whose picture is working.

[image]

I do se some errors in the FULLIMPORT in MIM, that might very well be reason for this behavior, but there is no additional error details to dig it further.

[image]

What could be causing the difference between the seemingly similar users? I've compared the AD profiles but haven't been able to find anything suspicious. Any tips on how to get better error messages from MIM?

Comment: Have you read what harbar.net has on the topic? Does it explain anything?

Comment: Yes I have, but to no avail. After few sessions with MS Premier Support, we got it working somehow, but couldnät really pinpoint exact cause for the issue. We just reconfigured it a few times and then it gradually started working...